# Install Swampy module in Python 3.5.0 (which is installed through Anaconda)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda, swampy

I have installed Python 3 using Anaconda and I need to install the Swampy module. Could you please advice me on how to proceed?

Comment: pip install swampy or conda install swampy ?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a `conda` package for it. So use `pip`:

```
pip install swampy
```

works also with Anaconda installed Python.

The installer `conda` that comes with Anaconda knows about the newly installed package:

```
conda list
....

swampy                    2.1.7                     <pip>
```

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried this, however I am getting this message:

C:\Users\sony>conda install swampy
Fetching package metadata: ....
Error: No packages found in current w

Did you mean one of these?

    sympy

You can search for this package on an

    anaconda search -t conda swampy

Comment: What does *this is not working*  mean? Any traceback, error message?

Comment: Hi Mike, I also pasted the message I was getting after typing the command. Someone also opinionated that swampy module works for Python 2.7 and not for 3.5.